# Creating a Contact Form in CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, profile

(I use CiviCRM with Wordpress, so I can't use the Drupal/CiviCRM contact form integration.)

I am trying to create contact forms for my website. I feel like using Profiles is the best way to do this, but I can't figure out how to have a "message" field where the user can write their message to submit. I can get the name, email fields into the profile fine, but there seems to be no way to give them a space to write an enquiry. "Notes" is the closest thing, but their old notes would be overwritten so it would not be ideal.

Is there some way to include an enquiry form with a Profile?

Comment: You can create new fields using custom field option of civicrm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to give a bit more insights, you are on the right path.

The final step is to add, as you said, the default Contact notes Civi has for each contact, the notes field is a **Multiple record set field**, which as it's own name says allows to create multiple data entries for the same set of fields, ie. you can have 10 notes entries, so every time a user submits the form it will create a new note instead of updating a existing one. Please note that the Multiple record field is only available for the Contacts entity, also make sure that the profile is set to update in the settings accordion.

If you don't want to use the existing Notes that Civi provides then you could create a new set of custom fields, navigating to **Administer - Customize data and screens - Custom fields - Add set of custom fields** give it the desired name (for example Enquiry),  *Used for* -> select  **Contacts** once done a checkbox will appear saying something like ***Does this custom set allow multiple records*** make sure you check it. You could display it as a **Tab** and add a custom field like Subject (Alphanumeric - Text) and a second field Message/Enquiry (Note - Text/Rich text). Once finished you can add the created custom fields to your profile. If I didn't explained myself you can always have a look at CiviCRM [documentation](http://book.civicrm.org/user/organising-your-data/custom-fields/) or leave a comment here.

PS: if you go the custom field path, you will also have to give the **Access all custom data** permission to anonymous users if applies, **User and Permission - Permission (Access control) - Wordpress Access Control**

Answer (score 3):

As Prem Patel said, you may add a custom field assigned to contacts and use this in your profile. If that's no good, try utilizing the notes field on contacts.

Answer (score 3):

In WordPress I use [Caldera Forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/caldera-forms/) with [CiviCRM integration](https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm) to create an Activity.  This maps better to the data - you want their message to be part of the act of contacting you, not part of their actual contact.

Additionally:

- You get lots of useful fields (like the timestamp) for free.
- If you have multiple contact forms for different purposes, you can easily distinguish between them with different activity types (or a custom field if you prefer).

Answer (score 0):

I've done both options that Andrei mentions above, the email out to both client and administrators always shows the 1st note value in the multiple record set and not the message/note/inquiry that was submitted by the customer.